# Get all JSON responses from array of Promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I want to make multiple calls for which I have to wait for the answer, and afterwards I want to group all responses in an array. I've not succeeded to do this.

The `res` constant in code below still retains the array of promises, not their results. I have no idea what else to try. No other stackoverflow answers have been helpful.

What I've tried:

```
const getProjectData = async (projectID) => await callAPI(`/projects/${projectID}`);

  const solve = async () => {
    const projects = [];
    currentUserProjectIDs.forEach((project) => {
      projects.push(getProjectData(project));
    });

    console.log("projects", projects);

    const res = await Promise.all(projects);
    console.log("solve res", res);
    return res;
  };

  const res = await solve();
  console.log("res", res);
```

Below is the result of the last console log:

```
res [
  Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'http://localhost:4000/projects/1',
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Headers],
      counter: 0
    }
  },
  Response {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'http://localhost:4000/projects/4',
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'OK',
      headers: [Headers],
      counter: 0
    }
  }
]
```

`callAPI` function:

```
export const callAPI = async (path, body, method = "GET") => {
  const config = {
    method: method,
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };
  if (body) {
    config.body = JSON.stringify(body);
  }
  const URL = `${process.env.HOST}${path}`;
  return await fetch(URL, config);
};
```

EDIT:
I have tried another way, but still unsuccessful. In the code below, the console.log inside the second `.then()` logs the correct data, but the returned `prj` is still an empty array...

```
const solve = async () => {
    const projects = [];
    currentUserProjectIDs.map((p) => {
      callAPI(`/projects/${p}`)
        .then((r) => {
          return r.json();
        })
        .then((a) => {
          console.log("a", a);
          projects.push(a);
          return a;
        });
    });
    return projects;
  };

  const prj = await solve();
  console.log("prj", prj);
```

Comment: Sounds peculiar, your code looks like it should work. Can you edit a live Stack Snippet into the question that demonstrates the problem? (you could implement `callAPI` with something like `Promise.resolve`)

Comment: Your output is not an array of promises, it's an array of Response objects.

Comment: @Evert well, okay, but how can I get my data out of them?

Comment: Iterate the array

Comment: @DanielA.White ehm, how? The elements of the array are far from what I get when making a single `callAPI` call. What I have here is not the JSON I need. But I presume there is a way of extracting the actual JSON data from the response. Could you help me with this?

Comment: "*The res constant in code below still retains the array of promises*" - no. It contains an array of `Response` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit is almost correct, but you have to use the array returned from `.map` and include the `Promise.all` from your original post:

```
const solve = async () => {
   const projects = currentUserProjectIDs.map((p) => {
     return callAPI(`/projects/${p}`)
        .then((r) => {
          return r.json();
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(projects);
  };

  const prj = await solve();
  console.log("prj", prj);
```

Pushing to a separate array won’t work because the code in `.then` is executed asynchronously.

You will probably also want to handle errors with `.catch`, I assume you omitted that for brevity.

Comment: Neither of these work. The first pushes to the `projects` asynchronously, the second returns `undefined` from the `map` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit cleaner solution based on your first attempt:

```
export const callAPI = async (path, body, method = 'GET') => {
  const config = {
    method: method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }

  if (body) {
    config.body = JSON.stringify(body)
  }

  const URL = `${process.env.HOST}${path}`
  const res = await fetch(URL, config)

  if (!res.ok) throw new Error('Error fetching data')

  return res.json()
}

const getProjectData = (projectID) => callAPI(`/projects/${projectID}`)

const solve = () => {
  const projects = currentUserProjectIDs.map((project) => {
    return getProjectData(project)
  })

  return Promise.all(projects)
}

solve()
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

The problem was (before your first edit) that you never called the `json()` method of the response, that's why you were getting an array of `Response` objects.

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
  const getProjectData = async (projectID) => await callAPI(`/projects/${projectID}`);
    
  const solve = async () => {
    const res = await Promise.all(
     currentUserProjectIDs
       .map(id => getProjectData(id)
       .then(res => res.json())
   );
    return res;
  };
  const res = await solve();
```

Comment: Better move the `.json()` call right inside the `getProjectData` function. And don't forget to check the status of the response!

Comment: @Bergi, thanks for your remark, it makes sense. I just wanted to show the reason why he is not given an array of results.